# Select distinct record and return latest based on a datetime column

Tags: sql, presto

I'd like to get among all my records only one example per `customer_id` and choose the one with the latest `updated_at` column.
Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT  user_id,
        customer_id,
        MAX(updated_at)
FROM Customers
WHERE userid = 'xyz'
GROUP BY customer_id
```

However, when using this method, I always have to add in the group by any column that I want to return, which doesn't work for my use case.

Is there a different method to achieve this ?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: You can use outer sub query first.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way, this way you just show the column you choose without dealing with a group by

```
SELECT  *

FROM Customers a where not exists
(
select 1 from Customers b where a.userid = b.userid and a.updated_at < b.updated_at
)
WHERE userid = 'xyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery :

```
select c.*
from Customers c
where c.userid = 'xyz' and 
      c.updated_at = (select max(c1.updated_at) 
                      from Customers c1 
                      where c1.customer_id = c.customer_id
                     );
```